# Generating route from user's current location to desired location on web map created in QGIS?

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, routing, open-source-routing-machine

I am developing a GIS in QGIS and I want to get the user's current location, then according to the user's second point selection, I want to generate a route between these two points. If possible, I want routing to be based on walking, not car.

I want to use OpenStreetMap as the base map.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

I want this to be done on a web map after creating it using the qgis2web plugin. I have looked at OSRM but I can't find out how exactly to use it on this system.

Comment: OSRM has a REST API which you can use in your system to get the route geometry. Get started sending a simple route request to OSRM and show it in your map.

Comment: Hey @Mesa , thanks for the response. I am stuck on how I can start on that, can you please show me more directions, links perhaps?

Comment: Because you want to do this in the webmap generated by qgis2web, this isn't really a QGIS issue. Can you retag your question with Leaflet and/or OpenLayers, depending on which format you are exporting your map in?

Comment: Ok, thanks @Tom Chadwin. Any suggestions on how I can work with it? The map is being generated by OpenLayers

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mesa you can start by generating a route request which should provide you with an output json that you can parse to retrieve the route. You can then create a vector layer and add it to the map.

[OSRM API Documentation](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.15.2/api/#general-options) provides all the necessary information (including example requests) to get you started.

Example:

`http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/foot/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?geometries=geojson`

Output:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            13.3888,
            52.517033
          ],
          [
            13.388625,
            52.518883
          ],
          [
            13.388024,
            52.52175
          ],
          [
            13.388898,
            52.521997
          ],
          [
            13.391643,
            52.522074
          ],
          [
            13.391718,
            52.522858
          ],
          [
            13.393549,
            52.526228
          ],
          [
            13.392425,
            52.528233
          ],
          [
            13.397631,
            52.529432
          ]
        ],
        "type": "LineString"
      },
      "legs": [
        {
          "summary": "",
          "weight": 627.6,
          "duration": 458.8,
          "steps": [],
          "distance": 1879.4
        }
      ],
      "weight_name": "routability",
      "weight": 627.6,
      "duration": 458.8,
      "distance": 1879.4
    }
  ],
  "waypoints": [
    {
      "hint": "598JgGxZ5oQoAAAAOgAAAA8AAAAAAAAAeOI0QY6li0FoZYRAAAAAACgAAAA6AAAADwAAAAAAAAByoQAAAEzMAKlYIQM8TMwArVghAwEA3wr1yOx5",
      "name": "Friedrichstraße",
      "location": [
        13.3888,
        52.517033
      ]
    },
    {
      "hint": "uZsTgLfVvIEOAAAADAAAAHMBAAAAAAAA4pzIQFu_j0CGdCVDAAAAAA4AAAAMAAAAcwEAAAAAAAByoQAAf27MABiJIQOCbswA_4ghAwIAnxD1yOx5",
      "name": "Torstraße",
      "location": [
        13.397631,
        52.529432
      ]
    }
  ],
  "code": "Ok"
}
```